# Sharepoint authentication error 403 using java

Tags: java, sharepoint

I am trying to authenticate to sharepoint, but i am getting 403 error.
URL is in HTTPS.

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
                    new NTCredentials("xxx@xxx.com", "Password", "https://xxx.xxx.com", "xxx.com"));
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                    .build();
            System.out.println("credsProvider"+credsProvider);
            System.out.println("httpclient"+httpclient);

        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://xxx.xxx.com/_api/web/lists");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
```

any solution ?